# Sort a list by weight, picking up the start of an item and assigning it a custom weight

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, dom

I would like to sort a list based on the title / description of the element.

Depending on the **first word**, assign a weight to later define a custom order.

From:

- **Third** element in list 4 200
- **First** element in list 3 200
- **First** element in list 3 200
- **Fourth** element in list 5 200
- **Second** element in list 2 200
- **Second** element in list 2 200

To:

- **First** element in list 3 200
- **First** element in list 3 200
- **Second** element in list 2 200
- **Second** element in list 2 200
- **Third** element in list 4 200
- **Fourth** element in list 5 200

> Any title that we are not controlling, will be assigned a
>   predetermined weight (the heaviest) so that it appears at the end.

```js
var list = $('.list');
var listItems = list.children('li').get();

$(listItems).each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var description, focusDescription;
  var weight;
  
  description = $this.find('span.description a').text();
  focusDescription = description.split(' ')[0];

  switch (focusDescription) {
    case 'First':
      weight = 1;
      // code block logic
      break;
    case 'Second':
      weight = 2;
      // code block logic
      break;
    case 'Third':
      weight = 3;
      // code block logic
      break;
    case 'Fourth':
      weight = 4;
      // code block logic
      break;
    default:
      weight = 5;
      // code block logic
  }

});

listItems.sort(function(a, b) {
  // code block logic
})
$.each(listItems, function(idx, itm) {
  list.append(itm);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-element">
    <span class="description">
            <a href="#">Third element in list</a>
        </span>
    <span class="years">4</span>
    <span class="EC">200</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-element">
    <span class="description">
            <a href="#">First element in list</a>
        </span>
    <span class="years">3</span>
    <span class="EC">200</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-element">
    <span class="description">
            <a href="#">First element in list</a>
        </span>
    <span class="years">3</span>
    <span class="EC">200</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-element">
    <span class="description">
            <a href="#">Fourth element in list</a>
        </span>
    <span class="years">5</span>
    <span class="EC">200</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-element">
    <span class="description">
            <a href="#">Second element in list</a>
        </span>
    <span class="years">2</span>
    <span class="EC">200</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-element">
    <span class="description">
            <a href="#">Second element in list</a>
        </span>
    <span class="years">2</span>
    <span class="EC">200</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question, what is going wrong?

Comment: My example code lacks a certain logic to work, I would like the list to be sorted according to the weight of the first word I capture.

Comment: This looks like a question from a lecturer/teacher.

Comment: People are not gonna fix your problems for free. Show us what you tried so far?

Comment: This is a work-arround to solve a Drupal issue listing with its default weights assignments. Not actually a school exercice or something. But that means that I have asked the question quite well, I suppose!

Comment: Well, right now you're basically asking us: This is what I want, this is my code, fix it. That's not how StackOverflow works, You can hire a freelancer to do that. Show us how you tried to fix the issue and what did that result in? Did you get error messages or an unexpected outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort these with defining a JS object with will give priority to each word. So you will use this priority as a rank for your sort function. Your js code will be like below:

```js
var rank = {
    First:0,
    Second:1,
    Third:2,
    Fourth:3,
}
var list = $('.list');
var listItems = list.children('li').get();

listItems.sort(function(a, b) {
  return rank[$(a).find('span.description a').text().split(' ')[0]] - rank[$(b).find('span.description a').text().split(' ')[0]]
})
$.each(listItems, function(idx, itm) {
  list.append(itm);
});
```

Comment: Welcome. Yeah you can use to this type of programming

Comment: This approach has a missing thing, https://jsfiddle.net/Qu4k3/btL3unyw/ when a element is not controlled, the elements above it are not ordered.